# How to match database column header names with values from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two drop-down menus. In the first drop down, I have hard-coded the names of columns of database i.e. same names as they are in database columns. Now in the second drop-down menu, I want to match that selected column name from the first drop down with the column name from the database.
I don't know how to match with database column header names using query and show the rows of that selected column in the second drop-down menu. Here is the code:

```html
<select name="first">
<option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Select an Option</option> 
  <option value="all">Select All</option>   
  <option value="name">Name</option>
  <option value="course">Course</option>
  <option value="roll_no">Roll No</option>
</select>
```

This is my first drop-down menu. The names given in value are the same as the column names of the database table.

Answer (score 0):

This is sample of what I am using to print HTML selectbox which takes data from DB. This is written for MSSQL but it can be remade for mysql. It is using prepared statements as you always should when dealing with user inputs.

```
$params = array(&$id, &$param);
$query = "Your query";
$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);
sqlsrv_execute($stmt); 
PrintSelectBoxWithOptions($stmt,$session_filter_ope_id,'process');
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);    

function PrintSelectBoxWithOptions($stmt,$select_name)
{
    echo'<select name="'.$select_name.'" class="selectbox">';
    while(($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))!= null) 
    {
        printf('<option value="%s" >%s</option>',$row[0],$row[1]);   
    }
    echo'</select>';
}
```